# React - onClick setTimeout/clear old timeout if there is one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a toy project where I generate a lot of tints and shades of colors and clicking on them copies their hex values to the clipboard. Originally, I was using an onClick handler on the color article to set my state value `alert` to true (which would display "copied to clipboard") and using useEffect to set a 3 second timer with setTimeout before turning `alert` false so that the text would disappear after awhile.

The relevant code inside my Color component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(false);
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [alert]);
```

and

```
  return (
    <article
      className={`color ${index > (list.length - 1) / 2 ? "color-light" : ""}`}
      style={{ backgroundColor: `rgb(${rgbString})` }}
      onClick={() => {
        setAlert(true);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(hexValue);
      }}
    >
      <p className="percent-value">{weight}%</p>
      <p className="color-value">{rgbToHex(...rgb)}</p>
      {alert && <p className="alert">copied to clipboard</p>}
    </article>
  );
```

This works, but in the case of multiple clicks on the same color article, I want to have the "copied to clipboard" alert disappear 3 seconds after the *last* click. In other words, I want multiple clicks to refresh the timer. Currently, it disappears 3 seconds after the first click, so subsequent clicks do not refresh the timer. This is because subsequent clicks on the color don't change the `alert` state value, so I can't refresh my timer in useEffect. I tried to solve this by calling `setAlert(false)` before `setAlert(true)` in my onClick to force the state to change every click and let me enter useEffect by force but this doesn't work. I've also tried different ways of removing useEffect entirely and trying to do everything in the onClick block since it's semantically closer to what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure out how to achieve my result that way. Any pointers?

Comment: You can use something like throttle. You can clear timeout inside `setTimeout`. And why do you use `useEffect` for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare a variable alertTimeout outside of your component:

```
let alertTimeout;
function MyComponent(props) {
...
}
```

And in your component you define a function for the timeout triggering/refreshing :

```
function triggerAlert() {
  if (alertTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(alertTimeout);
  }
  setAlert(true);
  alertTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    setAlert(false);
  }, 3000);
}
```

And you call this function with onClick:

```
onClick={() => {
    triggerAlert();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(hexValue);
  }}
```

And you need to add a uesEffect to clear the timeout on component unmount:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return function cleaning() {
    if (alertTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(alertTimeout);
    }
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: I thought using a global variable won't work because the user can click on different color components (which will have different setTimeouts).

Also, as I'm new to react, can you explain why you are passing an empty dependency array to useEffect in this case? I've tried it without it, and contrary to my expectations, it didn't work.

Comment: Concerning the different setTimeouts related to the different color component, you should post your question with the whole scope of your problem, in order to get comprehensive answers.

useEffect with an empty dependency array will be triggered just once, at the mounting of the component. The returned function will be called just once at the unmounting of the component. You said "I've tried it without it, and contrary to my expectations, it didn't work." Do that means that it works with the empty dependency array ?